# How can I make new account by JSON-RPC of Go

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

I'd like to make new account by JSON-RPC.I've checked the wiki of Ethereum, however I could not find out how to do that.

I've found call existed accounts, but it isn't what I want.
eth_accounts

Could you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Using the personal API over RPC is usually a bad idea. If you are on the same local computer as the node, try using IPC

Answer (score 0):

you need first to enable personal API using `geth --rpc --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal"`

then run your rpc call :

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_newAccount","params":["password"],"id":1}' localhost:8545
```

Here's the documentation link for newAccount
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#personal_newaccount